# MvxLoaderPluginRegistry.AddConventionalPlugin is missing after update to MvvmCross 4.1.4

Tags: plugins, xamarin, mvvmcross

`MvxLoaderPluginRegistry.AddConventionalPlugin` is missing after update to MvvmCross `4.1.4`. Now I can see a set or `Register` methods which have different signature:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a45cb515844f935b8b8ca04cf905342665a53fb9/MvvmCross/Platform/Platform/Plugins/MvxLoaderPluginRegistry.cs

How to load plugins after the update?

Comment: Note that the plugin registry is refactored in 4.1.4: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugins are loaded via `Bootstrappers`. These bootstrappers automatically install with the MvvmCross plugins in the folder `Bootstrap`. `$rootnamespace` will get replaced with the root namespace of the target project when you install the plugin via NuGet.

**iOS Bootstrapper**

Inherits from `MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction`.

```cs
namespace $rootnamespace$.Bootstrap
{
    public class BlePluginBootstrap
        : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE.PluginLoader, MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE.iOS.Plugin>
    {
    }
}
```

**Android Bootstrapper**

Inherits from `MvxPluginBootstrapAction`.

```cs
namespace $rootnamespace$.Bootstrap
{
    public class BlePluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

[image: bootstrappers of installed plugins]

**Pluginloader**

```cs
public class PluginLoader
  : IMvxPluginLoader
{
    public static readonly PluginLoader Instance = new PluginLoader();

    public void EnsureLoaded()
    {
        var manager = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
        manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
    }
}
```

**Plugin**

Each plugin has its platform specific `Plugin` class that registers the implementation of the interfaces.

```cs
namespace MvvmCross.Plugins.BLE.Droid
{
    public class Plugin
     : IMvxPlugin
    {
        public void Load()
        {
            Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IAdapter>(() => new Adapter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, Bootstraps were there but code wasn't working. This was helpful: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Answer (score 3):

It is true. `MvxLoaderPluginRegistry` does not have such method in MvvmCross 4.1.4 anymore.

It is recommended to use Bootstrap class to load plugins. You can check [MvvmCross example](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/49932c5b84dbf6210f4524b1ee08e5de85f0092e/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.Droid/Bootstrap/ColorPluginBootstrap.cs) to see how to load both conventional and unconventional approaches.

NOTE: You can use `MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction` for all platforms now (before 4.1.4 this bootstrap worked only on iOS/Mac platforms)

Though, if you still want to use `Registry` to load plugins you have to specify platform specific class using new methods:

```cs
public override AddPluginsLoaders (MvxLoaderPluginRegistry registry)
{
    // Register plugin using types
    registry.Register<MyPlugin.PluginLoader, MyPlugin.iOS.Plugin>();

    // Registeer plugin using factory method
    registry.Register<MyPlugin.PluginLoader>(() => new MyPlugin.iOS.Plugin());
}

// Don't forget to load these plugins
public override void LoadPlugins(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
{
    pluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded<MyPlugin.PluginLoader>();
    base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);
}
```